# Expected value for Head/Tails

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, contest-math

There are $N$ coins placed in a line. A coin may be facing head/tail direction with $0.5$ probability. Now I need to find number of pairs of coins $(i,j)$ such that $i<j$ and on index $i$ , I should get Head, and on index $j$ I should get Tail. Means head on left and tail on right.

Examples:

HTHTT has 5 pairs

HTHT has 3 pairs

THTH has 1 pair.

Find the expected value of number of such pairs ( when given $N$).

Comment: Bit confused with the question, why does the first one have 3?

Comment: one between first H and first T, one between second H and Second T, and third between second H and Third T.

Comment: okay, so you need H on the left, T on the right and only T in between? so HTTTT has 4 but HTHTHT only has 3?

Comment: Wellcome to MSE. If you make your question clear and show your trial, then you would obtain good feedback. Nice to meet you !

Comment: HTHTHT has 6 pairs i just want pairs(i,j) in which i<j and on i I should have head , and on j I should have tail.

Comment: Then shouldn't HTHT in your example have 3?

Comment: Yeah Corrected it. Thanks

Comment: And should your first example, HTHTT have 5?

Comment: Seems like it. Please clean up the question and show us what you've tried, and it'll make it a lot easier for us to help. Welcome to MSE, by the way :)

Comment: This question is an attempt to cheat in a programming competition http://www.codechef.com/TCFS15P/ . "Learner" has posted four questions here today from the same competition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you flip a tail, you score a point for each previous head that you've already flipped.

Let $E_n$ be the expected score for $n$ flips. We should have that flipping an $(n+1)$-st coin gives us an expected additional score of $\frac12\cdot\frac{n}2=\frac{n}{4}$.  The reasoning is that half the time we flip a head and get no additional points; and half the time we flip a tail and score a point for each previous head, and we expect half the previous flips to be heads.

Thus $E_n$ obeys the recursion: $E_0=0$ and $E_{n+1}=E_n+\frac{n}{4}$

This solves out to $E_0=E_1=0$ and $E_n=\frac{1+2+\cdots+(n-1)}{4}=\frac{n(n-1)}{8}$ for $n\ge 2$.

Comment: Thanks . This was very helpful.